# Does StreetViewPublishServiceClient refresh access token automatically before calling API?

Tags: python, client, google-oauth, access-token, google-street-view

I've got below error when calling api of `street_view_publish_service_client`. It seems my token is expired...

> GaxError(RPC failed, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated
>   with (StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED, Request had invalid authentication
>   credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other
>   valid authentication credential. See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.)>)

Is access token of credentials refreshed automatically before calling API of StreetViewPublishServiceClient? If not, how can I refresh access token?
Here are sample codes.

```
pip install gapic-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1
pip install google-auth


from google.streetview.publish.v1 import street_view_publish_service_client
import google.oauth2.credentials

def run():
  creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
      MY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      refresh_token=MY_REFRESH_TOKEN,
      token_uri="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
      client_id=GOOGLE_CLINET_ID,
      client_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET) 

    client = street_view_publish_service_client.StreetViewPublishServiceClient(
        credentials=creds)

    upload_ref = client.start_upload()
    print upload_ref
```

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues in my answer, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification?

```
from google.streetview.publish.v1 import street_view_publish_service_client
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google.auth.transport.requests # Added

def run():
    creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        MY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        refresh_token=MY_REFRESH_TOKEN,
        token_uri="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
        client_id=GOOGLE_CLINET_ID,
        client_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET) 

    creds.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request()) # Added
    client = street_view_publish_service_client.StreetViewPublishServiceClient(
        credentials=creds)

    upload_ref = client.start_upload()
    print upload_ref
```

#### Note :

- This modification supposes that before the expiration time of access token is over, the access token had been working for your script.

#### Reference :

- [google.auth.transport.requests](http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.transport.requests.html)

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.